# DraggableScrollableSheet issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

i have 2 pages. A and B page. i navigate to B page from A page. in B page i have DraggableScrollableSheet. when i expand to `maxChildSize` by scrolling it scroll fine. but when i try to scroll back to `initialChildSize` and `minChildSize`, this B page is closing and navigating back to A page. this is my code:

````
  Widget _detailWidget() {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      maxChildSize: 1,
      initialChildSize: .64,
      minChildSize: .64,
      builder: (context, scrollController) {
        return Container(
          padding: AppTheme.padding.copyWith(bottom: 0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                topRight: Radius.circular(40),
              ),
              color: Colors.white),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: scrollController,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 5,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: LightColor.iconColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TitleText(text: "Title Looooong", fontSize: 25),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TitleText(
                                text: "\$ ",
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: LightColor.red,
                              ),
                              TitleText(
                                text: "124",
                                fontSize: 25,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.star,
                                  color: LightColor.yellowColor, size: 17),
                              Icon(Icons.star,
                                  color: LightColor.yellowColor, size: 17),
                              Icon(Icons.star,
                                  color: LightColor.yellowColor, size: 17),
                              Icon(Icons.star,
                                  color: LightColor.yellowColor, size: 17),
                              Icon(Icons.star_border, size: 17),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                _availableSize(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                _availableColor(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                _description(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: _flotingButton(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color(0xfffbfbfb),
              Color(0xfff7f7f7),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          )),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _productImage(),
              _appBar(),
              _detailWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```

here `_productImage()` and `_appbar()` are just widgets. what might be problem
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to check that you are initially controllers well.

Comment: there is only one scrollController. what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem. it is because i used modalBottomSheet navigation to B page from A page